# expressing events in binary scenario: A machine produces pieces, either U: useable or N: unuseable

Tags: probability

So I need some help with my homework. Please tell if im in the wrong place I will delete the question by myself then.

The question:

A machine produces pieces. The pieces are either U: useable or N: unuseable.

Express the following events with U and N.

- A: All three pieces are usable.
- B: The first and the third piece is unusable.
- C: Only the first and the third are unusable.
- D: Two pieces are usable.
- E: The usable and the unusable alternate.

This seems way to easy to just write down A: (UUU), B: (NUN, NNN). Any help?

Comment: The book probably has some notation for events that you're expected to use.  Something like $X_1=U\land X_2=U\ landX_3=U$ for the first, perhaps, where $X_k$ is the status of the $k$th piece produced.

Comment: And how would I write the mathematically correct solution then?

Comment: I don't know what your teacher expects.  I would write "Let $X_k$ be the status of the $k$th piece produced," and then continue as in my first comment, but again, I don't know if that's what's expected.  Your book or your class notes should give you better guidance.

Comment: Alright thank you very much that helped me :)